# message-driven-channel-adapter time limit processing

Tags: spring-integration, spring-transactions

Is it possible to specify how long the processing of the message should be, and if exceeded, throw TIMEOUT exception? I tried setting transaction timeout, but that didn't work. The time passed, no exception was thrown. Even the DefaultTransactionDefinition.getTimeout() method was not invoked (had a breakpoint in the debugger). The DefaultTransactionDefinition.setTimeout(int) was called with the right value.

Here is my setup:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="x"
                                        channel="incoming"
                                        container="my"
                                        error-channel="errors"/>
```

Container "my" extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer and this is where I have:

```
@Override
@Autowired
@Value("5")
public void setTransactionTimeout(final int transactionTimeoutInSec)
{
  super.setTransactionTimeout(transactionTimeoutInSec);
}
```

Is there some other way? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the problem that you don't configure external `transaction-manager`?..

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can do something similar for at least raw java, not Spring Integration. I mean that I don't know any possible way to limit the method invocation duration. Of, course, we can do that somehow via async invocation and some thread barrier to wait and interrupt with a desired exception. At least that is how `timeout` works on `<gateway>`. But that one is for request-reply. In your case it is one-way flow.

Although you can consider some AOP advice with async handoff like I suggested and `CountDownLatch` for each message to wait and limit the wait period by desired `timeout`.

From other side there out-of-the-box component like [`<barrier>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#barrier), which really may help you there:

1. You need `<recipient-list-router>` with a first `ExecutorChannel` recipient to send a message to the target service
2. The second recipient should be `DirectChannel` for `<barrier>` to block the main thread for desired `timeout` or good result.
3. You should figure out somewhere in the real service flow how to `trigger` `BarrierHandler`  to release main thread properly.
4. Don't forget to configure its `require-reply` to `true`. In that case the `ReplyRequiredException` is thrown. You should catch somehow (e.g. `error-channel`'s handler and wrap it into desired `TimeoutException`)
5. Don't forget to specify some proper `correlation-strategy` to.

But... Be sure that it isn't an overhead for your system and let's try to understand if you really need to worry about that processing timeout.